# Array showing error on tbody

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code, I don't know whats wrong with this piece of code.

```
var tst= this.apptDataTable.find("tbody:last")
```

am getting value but when i add

```
var tst= this.apptDataTable.find("tbody:last")[0]
```

It's showing undefined.

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Show us the output of  `console.log( this.apptDataTable.find("tbody:last") )`..

Comment: `.find("tbody:last")` returns a jQuery object. `.find("tbody:last")[0]` returns a DOM Element. Hence if you try and call method expecting one type of object and get a completely different one, you're going to have issues. We need to see the code where you're attempting to use `tst`, and any errors you get in the console.

Comment: am not getting any error,its showing undefined when i use [0]

Comment: if (tst.rows.length == 0) { //do smt }   here am getting unable to get undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you add the index `[0]`?

And `:last` select SINGLE element which is the last one.